# Understanding on drop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build a regsiter form - and handler function for check the values of the inputs.

When someone focus on input or keyup something - a checking function is running.

Now I'm trying to make a handler for drop text into the input.
I want to run the validation when the user drop text into the input (ex. select some text in the page and drag and drop it into the input).

What I found out is when the user drop the text into the input - the value of the input isn't updating. only when the user exit the input (focusout?) the input value is updating.

What can I do for making the on drop event update the value in the time the text is dropped into the input, and not only after the user is exit the input???

---

Example of my code:

```
    $("#register_form input").on("keyup focus change", function(){

        index = $(this).parent().index();

        // except submit input
        if (index != 4) {

            var input_name = $(this).attr("name");
            if (input_name == "register_password") {
                formInputHandler($(this), input_name, index);
                formInputHandler($("input[name='register_repassword']"), "register_repassword", 3);
            } else {
                formInputHandler($(this), input_name, index);
            }

            // check submit change
            formSubmitHandler();
        }
    });


    $("#register_form input").on("drop", function(event){
        ???
    });
```

Comment: try `.on("input")` instead of `.on("change")`

Comment: my problem is not the first function... it's the "on drop" function